# C++ Structure declaration and usage to hold IP + Connections

Tags: c++

Good day to all, i am having a massive confusion declaring and using my structure to hold **[IP] - [Connections]** record.
I am trying to insert the IP address that is connecting into the structure, and his connection number **#**, for example if **IP 123.123.12** connects 2 (two) times, then update the **[Connections]** number in the struct for that **IP (123.123.12)**.

I have the following code, wich should work:

```
// the struct
typedef struct {
    int id; // is this usefull anyway ?
    char *ip;
    int connNumbers;
}test_sock;

// init struct
test_sock holder[5000];
int len = 0;

// the function
void AddtoStruct(char *ip)
{

    if (len == 0) //if empty, insert.
    {
        len++;
        holder->id = len;
        holder->ip = ip;
        holder->connNumbers = 1; //1 conexiune

        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {



        if (test_sock->id != 0) //check if its the same id !?
        {
                //Exista deja in structura , doar increase connNumbers;
                if (strcmp(ip, holder->ip) == 0)
                {
                    holder++;
                    holder->connNumbers++;
                    holder->id = antiddos_len;
                    holder->ip = ip;



                    return; // should return or not ?!
                }
                else{ //new IP, insert into struct.
                    len++; // COUNT AGAIN ?
                    holder->id = len;
                    holder->ip = ip;
                    holder->connNumbers = 1; // 1 connection


                    return; // should return or not ?!
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so what it should is:
Check the new incoming **IP** if it`s **ALLREADY** in the structure, then increase the number of connections for that ip
If the new incoming **IP** is **NOT** inside the structure, insert it, and if he connects again, of course increase the number of connections.

I compiled a minimal example below, wich you can run without problems on a Windows machine, using Visual Studio (i used 2013).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

// the struct
typedef struct {
    int id; // is this usefull anyway ?
    char *ip;
    int connNumbers;
}test_sock;

// init struct
test_sock holder[5000];
int len = 0;

// the function
void AddtoStruct(char *ip)
{

    if (len == 0) //if the struct is empty, insert.
    {
        len++;
        holder->id = len;
        holder->ip = ip;
        holder->connNumbers = 1; //1 conexiune
        cout << "ADDED NEW IP: " << holder->ip << " Connections: " << holder->connNumbers << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {

        if (holder->id != 0) //verificam ca sa nu fie ACELASI ID
        {
            //Exista deja in structura , doar increase connNumbers;
            if (strcmp(ip, holder->ip) == 0)
            {
                len++;
                holder->connNumbers++;
                holder->id = len;
                holder->ip = ip;
                cout << "NEW CONNECTION FROM IP: " << holder->ip << " Connections: " << holder->connNumbers << endl;
                cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            }
            else{ //new IP, insert into struct.
                len++; // COUNT AGAIN ?
                holder->id = len;
                holder->ip = ip;
                holder->connNumbers = 1; // 1 connection
                cout << "CONNECTION FROM NEW IP: " << holder->ip << " Connections: " << holder->connNumbers << endl;
                cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                return; // should return or not ?!
            }
        }
    }
}

// use the function

int main() {

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";

    char *ip2 = "127.0.0.3";

    AddtoStruct(ip);
    Sleep(5); // wait for new IP
    AddtoStruct(ip2);
    Sleep(5); // wait for SAME IP
    AddtoStruct(ip);

    system("pause");
}
```

As you can see, if you run the code, it does not work as it should, it count the same number of connections for every new IP ...
So please give me advice, or a fix, or anything, because i really need this, and it`s been 3 days of testing, without any progress.
Many thanks!

Comment: Why not simply a `std::set<std::string>>` to hold the IP addresses? `char*` is a not so good idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - if you give me example, be sure i will :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, even better would be a (typedefed) type for the IP address, because not all strings are legal IP adresses. To the bug: You don't insert a new holder when you encounter a new IP

Comment: @Mecanik Well, your code is so c-ish it's a bit hard to turn it into valid c++ code What kind of example would you like to see in particular? I believe it's better you take a look at the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This code using std::vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct test_sock
{
    test_sock()
    {
        memset(IP, 0, sizeof(IP));
        con_count = 0;
    }
    char IP[15];
    int con_count;
};

vector<test_sock>data_holder;

void AddtoStruct(char *ip)
{
    if (ip == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: ip == NULL!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Try to verify if IP is already in data_holder
        vector<test_sock>::iterator itr = data_holder.begin();
        for (; itr != data_holder.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if (strcmp((*itr).IP, ip) == 0)
            {
                (*itr).con_count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If not, create new instance and save IP
        if (itr == data_holder.end())
        {
            data_holder.resize(data_holder.size() + 1);
            memcpy(data_holder[data_holder.size() - 1].IP, ip, strlen(ip));
            data_holder[data_holder.size() - 1].con_count = 1;
            // This handles new IPs
            cout << "[DATA HOLDER] ip: " << data_holder[data_holder.size() - 1].IP << " Connections: " << data_holder[data_holder.size() - 1].con_count << endl;
        }
        // Else increase con_count value for existing IP
        else
        {
            // This handles exists IPs
            cout << "[DATA HOLDER] ip: " << (*itr).IP << " Connections: " << (*itr).con_count << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    char *ip2 = "127.0.0.3";
    AddtoStruct(ip);
    AddtoStruct(ip2);
    AddtoStruct(ip);
    AddtoStruct(ip2);
    AddtoStruct(ip2);
    AddtoStruct(ip2);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking from your time and giving me the solution. This works exactly how i wanted, however i have a question, wich method is better to use, this with std::vector or struct? Many thanks again.

Comment: If you want to use STL, then the most appropriate container is the map.  Map looks after all the details of finding an existing IP and inserting a new one.

Comment: std::map is probably faster solution than iterating through vector. 
map using hash function.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

You should use this containers because they are providing "Infinite" space for your IPs .. and also allows you to easily manage it(add/delete and so).

Comment: PS. (The size of a memory which these containers can hold depends on your RAM size and an OS you're using.)

Comment: @Cruppy, it seems that after a period my application crashes... on debug i cannot see the problem, because i don`t have 500 proxy ip`s to connect them... :(

Comment: Try to resize IP array to IP[16];(it can cause problems)
I tried it and i can handle 100000+ adresses.

Comment: IP array in test_sock struct.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.  The worst is:

1. Do not add new IP when the first existing IP you check does not equal the IP being added.  Loop over them all and only add if NONE of the existing IPs match.

Pseudo-code:

```
unset found flag
loop over existing IPs
  if match
    increment count
    set found flag
    break out of loop
end loop
if found flag NOT set
  add new IP
```

Next problem is:

2. You are incrementing len even if the IP does match an existing one.  So if you have duplicates then len will be too long and you will loop over uninitialized values.

===============

FYI, here is the STL way of doing this.  It uses std::map which not only significantly reduces the amount of code required, it has an optimized find() function which will greatly reduce the time spent searching through the previous IPs when many, many have been added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map < string, int > IPCollection;

void AddToIPCollection( char* ip )
{
    map < string, int >::iterator it = IPCollection.find( string( ip ));
    if( it == IPCollection.end() )
    {
        // new IP
        IPCollection.insert( pair< string, int >( ip, 1 ) );
        cout << "CONNECTION FROM NEW IP: " << ip << " Connections: " << 1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // increment connection count of existing IP
        it->second += 1;
        cout << "NEW CONNECTION FROM IP: " << ip << " Connections: " << it->second << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    char *ip2 = "127.0.0.3";

    AddToIPCollection(ip);
    AddToIPCollection(ip2);
    AddToIPCollection(ip);

    return 0;
}
```

The performance of this should be adequate for up to a million unique IPs.  If you need more than this, you should be able to squeeze some extra performance ( both time and memory ) by converting the IPs to unsigned longs before storing them.

```
 map < unsigned long, int > IPCollection;
```

You will need to test carefully to discover where the performance penalty of converting the IPs from strings to unsigned longs is outweighed by the optimizing of finding and inserting with numbers rather than strings.